# CSS Selectors: Possible to select ONLY the second element?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

Is this even possible?

```html
<div class="column">
    <div> 
        <div> 
        </div>    
        <div> <!-- Definitely not this DIV! -->
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div>     <!-- THIS DIV ONLY! -->
    </div>    
</div>
```

The following CSS selector gets the one I've marked "Definitely not this DIV!".

```
.column div:last-child {
    background-color:red;
}
```

The following CSS selector gets the one I want AND the one I've marked "Definitely not this DIV!".

```
.column div + div {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Same goes for this one: It gets the one I want AND the one I've marked "Definitely not this DIV!".

```
.column div:first-child + div {
    background-color:red;
}
```

**Question:** Is this even possible to do with CSS that will be recognized by IE7? (I assume my solution will work with FF, Safari, Chrome, and X:nth-child(n) only works with IE9+) Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, why not use an ID or CLASS selector?

Comment: I'm just trying to keep everything tidy... but really I suppose it's a form of premature optimization. `*gets coat*`

Comment: The only reason I say that is that the example at least seems to demonstrate a known form (columns in a layout), so if it's static and semantic, I would think an ID/CLASS would be appropriate in such a case.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It is a known, and it shouldn't be changing any time soon. Have I just made a mistake in terms of best practice?

Comment: Nah, if it works cross-browser and you're happy with it, go with it. But, my own preference would be to use descriptive attributes within the markup as well as the CSS, just to increase the human-readability and debugging. :)

Comment: You're probably right, though. Like I said, I feel like this is a bit of premature optimization. It's a little leaner, but it affects readability quite bit. Hmm!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do it.

```
#column > div:first-child + div
```

<del>You were using a class selector to select an element with an ID.</del>

You may want to look through the [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching), as it's the direct descendant & sibling selectors that gives you the finesse to choose a particular DOM element.

Comment: Probably, but if he didn't catch it on the answer, there's no reason to assume he'd catch it during development. tyops have consequinces

Comment: I fixed it when I noticed your answer. Always a pain not to make typos when you're typing into SO.

Comment: actually, he didn't, but I don't mind giving him the cred. Sort by oldest, and mine will be on top.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My bad. You got there first (although you may want to take out the class selector thing as I've updated the question now :)

Comment: This is actually the best resource I've found: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Answer (score 4):

You need to toss in the child combinator `>` just after `#column`, otherwise the innermost `div`s will also be looked at:

```
#column > div:first-child + div
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
    #column > div + div {
        background-color:red;
    }

</style>
<div id="column">
    <div> 
        <div> 
        </div>    
        <div> <!-- Definitely not this DIV! -->
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div>     <!-- THIS DIV ONLY! -->
    </div>    
</div>
```